# Does std::array call default ctors?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, c++11

I have a class containing a std::array of QVariant:

```
    class MyClass()
    {
        typedef std::array<QVariant, 42> attribs_t;
        attribs_t                        m_Attribs;

    public:
        MyClass()
        {
            m_Attribs[0] = 41;
        }
    };
```

I now analyzed this project using Intel Parallel inspector and it detects
"uninitialized memory access" at `m_Attribs[0] = 41;`

Do i have to call the constructor of the elements in std::array manually or is this a false positive?

Answer (score 3):

The size of a `std::array` array is fixed at compile-time, and the default constructor (which your `MyClass` constructor invokes) default-constructs or copy-constructs every `QVariant` of the array. I.e. I'd expect that at the beginning of your constructor, there are 42 `QVariant` objects in your array and they are all invalid (i.e. `isValid()` returns false).

The assignment should have the same effect as

```
m_Attribs[0] = QVariant( 41 );
```

which seems okay to me.

In short: I'd tend to claim it's a false positive if it wasn't for Intel's good reputation. :-}

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is fine.

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

struct QVariant {
    QVariant () : v_(0) { std::cout << "Constructed" << std::endl; }
    QVariant & operator=(int x) { std::cout << "Assigned" << std::endl;
                                     v_ = x; return *this; }
    int v_;
    };

class MyClass {
    typedef std::array<QVariant, 5> attribs_t;  // 5 instead of 42
    attribs_t                        m_Attribs;

public:
    MyClass() {
        m_Attribs[0] = 41;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    MyClass mc;
    return 0;
}
```

should print:

```
Constructed
Constructed
Constructed
Constructed
Constructed
Assigned
```

And does (on gcc and clang)